# Robocopy is creating build error when project is in a folder having name in other than English

Tags: c++, visual-studio, post-build-event, robocopy

**Using robocopy command which is not working for Korean language path. But it works properly in English language.**

In my `postbuild` event I am using `robocopy` command to copy some dlls. This works perfectly in my system. But the same solution is not working when I put the code/project in a folder which name is in Korean language.

**자동** is the Korean string used as the folder name in which project code is present.

Can you please tell how can I use robocopy to work with korean language path?

## Edit

**I found a solution and added that as an answer to this question. But I wonder there might be a better answer. So if anyone know a better answer please post it.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head for quite a long time I found the solution.

I changed the `locale` of my system to korean and it worked.
The locale of system(windows 7) can be changed in the following mentioned way.

```
Control Panel --> Clock, Language, and Region --> Region and Language --> 
Administrative --> Change system locale
```

What it did in actual was "it changed the system `codepage` to 946(for korean)". **The default code page of system(windows) for English is 437.**

The command which can be used to know the current code page of system is `chcp`(CHANGE CODE PAGE). If you use this command then it will give you a result like `Active code page: 437`. Below link provides more detail about code page.

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/codepage_e.html

For knowing more about robocopy visit the following links.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx